# How does the position of the point of minimum of a 2D function change under coordinate transformation?

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima

Let's say that I have a function in two variables: $f(x,y)$ and I know that $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is the point of minimum for $f$.

Now imagine I do a generic linear transformation on the coordinates:

$\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} X\\ Y\end{pmatrix}=A \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$

where $A$ is a 2 by 2 matrix.

My question is : is it true that the point minimum of $f(X,Y)$ (call it $(X_{0},Y_{0})$) is the transformed of the old point of minimum (by the same transformation $A$)? So:

$\begin{pmatrix} X_{0}\\Y_{0} \end{pmatrix}=A \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x_{0}\\y_{0} \end{pmatrix}
$

Is this true or false in general? And in the second case, what are the properties that $A$ needs to have in order for it to be valid?

I ask this because I wanted to determine the point of min of a function by first doing a linear transformation on the coordinates, such that it is easier to find it, and then applying on the point  the inverse transformation to find it in the original old variables.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do u have a specific A or f? If A is a rotational matrix, then the minimum would not have to remain the same.

Comment: I understand your question in the following way: we have $z=f(x,y)$. In $(x_0, y_0)$ we get the minimum $z_0$ of $f$ on its domain $D$. Then we do a transformation of the domain variables $(X,Y)=A(x,y)$ with $A$ linear, and I assume injective. We ask for the minimum of $g$ such as $g(X,Y)=f(x,y)$, on its domain $A(D)$. Is it right? Then, yes, the minimum is attained on $(X_0,Y_0)=A(x_0,y_0)$. It does not depend upon $A$ being linear, anyway. As long as $A$ is injective it works (if $A$ is not injective then $g$ is ill-defined).

Comment: @bananapeel22 see edit

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni yes that looks like what I was asking. Except I don't understand why you write $g(X,Y)=f(x,y)$. Edit: Ok yes I guess it's true because if you write X and Y  in terms of x,y and plug it in the g(X,Y) function you get f(x,y). Anyways is there a theorem to justify that?

Comment: @Mathew That's to avoid saying "the new $f$" (which is what you say above). A function has only one definition. If you change it (e.g. by a change of variables), then it is a new function with a new name. $g$ is "the new $f$". Of course the two functions are related, i.e. when $(X,Y)=A(x,y), \; g(X,Y)=f(x,y)$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni For A to be injective what properties does A need to have as matrix? does it work if it just contains constants?

Comment: $A$ being a square matrix, it is injective iff it has a non-null determinant (and then it is actually a bijection).

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Great thanks! Anyways, does a specific theorem exist for the initial claim of my question ?

Comment: I don't think so. That's the kind of thing people accept without demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked in the comments whether there was a specific theorem for your initial claim, and I answered "I don't think so", here is a proof.
We'll have functions of one variable only, because having two variables does not change anything here: the unique variable can have a domain which is the cartesian product of the two variables domains.

$x_0$ is a minimum for $f$ on its domain $D$, is equivalent to:
$\forall x \in D, f(x) \ge f(x_0)$.

We do a change of variables: $X = A(x)$, where $A$ is injective on $D$.
Define $g$ on $A(D)$:
$\forall X \in A(D), \exists !\,x \in D, A(x)=X$ because $A$ is injective, so we can define $g(X)=f(x)$.
Then $\forall x \in D, g(A(x))=f(x)$.

Let $X_0=A(x_0)$. Then
$\forall X \in A(D), \exists !\,x \in D, X=A(x), f(x) \ge f(x_0),$
$g(X)=g(A(x))=f(x) \ge f(x_0)=g(A(x_0))=g(X_0)$.
We have proven $\forall X \in A(D), g(X) \ge g(X_0)$: $X_0$ is a minimum of $g$ on $A(D)$.

$A$ being injective, $A$ is a bijection between $D$ and $A(D)$, so $A^{-1}$ is well defined. Then if you find $X_0$ minimum of $g$ on $A(D)$, $x_0$ is obtained by $x_0=A(X_0)$.

Note: we have reasoned for *"a"* minimum. If $x_0$ is *"the"* minimum of $f$ on $D$ - meaning there is no other minimum - the reasoning is the same, except that
$\forall x \in D, f(x) \ge f(x_0)$ shall be replaced by
$\forall x \in D, x \ne x_0 \Rightarrow f(x) \gt f(x_0)$.